# tf.placeholder_with_default caused to error

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Short question. 
Why caused this line to error? :

```
x = tf.placeholder_with_default([0.0 for _ in range(784)], [None, 784], name='images')
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

This error occurs:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 2 for 'images' (op: 'PlaceholderWithDefault') with input shapes: [784].
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you make shape [None, 784] for the placeholder, but default value has shape [784]. So just add one more square bracket around default value, like:

```
x = tf.placeholder_with_default([[0.0 for _ in range(784)]], [None, 784], name='images')
```

So you have shape of [1,784]